# Do I need the mac developer program to enable handoff?

Tags: ios, macos, handoff

Do I need a mac developer program to enable handoff between an osx app and an ios one?
I have both done but while from ios to osx works without problems, the opposite way seems not working (iOS device can't see the mac).

With two iOS devices my code runs ok.

I already filled the NSUserActivity types. The mac app, in the "General" settings has the "none signing" and in build settings the code signing identity is set to my iOS development certificate (since I don't own a mac one).
Do I need the mac certificate to run handoff from mac to ios?

Thanks

Comment: As far as I understand, handoff only works between apps of the same team. That's what they say in the WWDC video. And as the team ID is part of the provisioning profile, I assume that handoff requires a signed app.

Comment: that was my **exact** feeling. I posted the question since the strange unidirectional behavior

Comment: Strange that you got one-directional Handoff working. I couldn't get it to go either way, with an iOS Enterprise membership and no Mac membership.

Comment: I've also got it working iOS -> OSX, but having trouble with OSX -> iOS. The Mac app is signed, and running in Release mode. Not sure what to try next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Officially](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Handoff/HandoffFundamentals/HandoffFundamentals.html): yes, you do.

> ... apps must either be distributed through the App Store or signed by the registered developer.